# How to get entrie from another controllers content and call self controller on missing

Tags: ember.js

This is code illustration:
http://jsbin.com/uzapuy/1/edit

I want to be able to access *test* by URL like so: http://jsbin.com/uzapuy/1#/test/2
Because entrie may already present in client side, I want to check that first and only if it missing fetch from server side.
Is that possible without DS.Store?

Answer (score 0):

In your `TestRoute`, can you not do something like:

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function(params) {

        // Find your controller that has the "fetch" method.
        var testController = this.controllerFor('test');

        // Check if there's an existing model with this ID.
        var existingModel  = testController.find('id', params.id);

        // Determine if we found a model or not.
        if (existingModel) {

            // If we found an existing model, then we can set this as the model.
            return existingModel;

        }

        // Otherwise we'll fetch it from the server.
        return testController.fetch(params.id);
    }

});
```

Also, bear it in mind that in your code, the `test` variable is `undefined`:

```
var tests = App.Test.create({id: id, name: 'fetched ' + id});
self.set('content', test);
```

You're after `tests`, I assume.

Comment: Updated my snippet: http://jsbin.com/uzapuy/5/edit
But if I use *find* method in testsController I got en error. If I use  findProperty method  - T get nothing in search result. For your attention, there are 2 controller 'Tests' and 'Test'.

Comment: You get an error because `TestController` needs to extend `ArrayController` to have access to `find`/`findProperty`, which I think is what you need.

Comment: But it is https://gist.github.com/greggyNapalm/4748934#file-gistfile1-html-L90 and line 53.

Comment: The reason was in prams.id type str instead of int.
This solves the problem:
var existingModel  = testsController.findProperty('id', parseInt(params.test_id, 10));